# Loop Issue with Local Variable

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, while-loop

I'm using Python (3.x) to create a simple program for an assignment. It takes a multiline input, and if there is more than one consecutive whitespace it strips them out and replaces it with one whitespace. [That's the easy part.] It must also print the value of the most consecutive whitespaces in the entire input.

Example:

```
input = ("This is   the input.")
```

Should print:

```
This is the input.
3
```

My code is below:

```
def blanks():
    #this function works wonderfully!
    all_line_max= []
    while True:
        try:
            strline= input()
            if len(strline)>0:
                z= (maxspaces(strline))
                all_line_max.append(z)
                y= ' '.join(strline.split())
                print(y)
                print(z)
            if strline =='END':
                break
        except:
            break
        print(all_line_max)

def maxspaces(x):
    y= list(x)
    count = 0
    #this is the number of consecutive spaces we've found so far
    counts=[]
    for character in y:
        count_max= 0
        if character == ' ':
            count= count + 1
            if count > count_max:
                count_max = count
            counts.append(count_max)
        else:
            count = 0
    return(max(counts))


blanks()
```

I understand that this is probably horribly inefficient, but it seems to almost work. My issue  is this: I would like to, once the loop is finished appending to all_lines_max, print the largest value of that list. However, there doesn't seem to be a way to print the max of that list without doing it on every line, if that makes sense. Any ideas on my convoluted code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just print the `max` of `all_line_max`, right where you currently print the whole list:

```
print(max(all_line_max))
```

but leave it at the *top* level (so dedent once):

```
def blanks():
    all_line_max = []
    while True:
        try:
            strline = input()
            if strline:
                z = maxspaces(strline)
                all_line_max.append(z)
                y = ' '.join(strline.split())
                print(y)
            if strline == 'END':
                break
        except Exception:
            break
    print(max(all_line_max))
```

and remove the `print(z)` call, which prints the maximum whitespace count per line.

Your `maxspaces()` function adds `count_max` to your `counts` list *each time a space is found*; not the most efficient method. You don't even need to keep a list there; `count_max` needs to be moved *out* of the loop and will then correctly reflect the maximum space count. You also don't have to turn the sentence into a list, you can *directly* loop over a string:

```
def maxspaces(x):
    max_count = count = 0

    for character in x:
        if character == ' ':
            count += 1
            if count > max_count:
                max_count = count
        else:
            count = 0

    return max_count
```

Comment: If I use the print(max(all_line_max)) suggested, with a sample input as below:
1   3     5   3
1    4

I get output of:
1 3 5 3
5 (the max spaces in that line)
1 4
5 (the max spaces overall)
I'd like there to only be one print if possible.

Comment: @Weens: Yes, you need to dedent once to leave it outside of the `while` loop.

Comment: In that case, it seems to not print at all if outside the while loop. That was the part that was tripping me up to begin with, it makes no sense.

Comment: @Weens: It does for me; type `END` and your loop ends, and prints the max space count.

Comment: Aha! My input didn't have an END. You can tell it's 1:30am over here. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Weens: if you replace `except:` with `except Exception:` you can use a keyboard interrupt to end the loop as well (`CTRL-C`).